# Should I protect strings given to subroutines?

Tags: string, perl

If I have a variable which have been defined as a string,

```
my $x = "abc";
sub p { ... }
```

do I then have to `p("$x")` or can just do `p($x)` or `p($hash->{x})`?

All works in my tests. Any downsides to not quote?

Comment: What results do you get when you try the options you present above?

Comment: All works in my tests.

Comment: The 3rd case shouldn't work because you haven't defined `$hash` in your example, but no you don't need to "guard" strings passed to subroutines.

Comment: Guys, the "try yourself" isn't the best answer. The OP could try something, and got the wanted result, but his "tried" method could have some side-effects what he didn't catch. This is a novice, but still legitime question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of whether it is used as a subroutine call parameter, it is generally considered to be bad practice to quote a single scalar variable, as in `"$s"`, for two reasons

- You are unnecessarily making a *duplicate* of the value
- You may be invoking an overloaded *stringify* behaviour

Of course, the second may also be a good reason to choose to do exactly this, because you *wanted* to use the stringify special behaviour.

The only downside with using a bare variable as a subroutine parameter is that, since Perl passes the values by reference, it is possible to modify that value from within the subroutine. However you would need to modify an element of `@_` which is very difficult to do accidentally.

The usual form of a subroutine is this

```
sub proc {
  my ($p1, $p2, $p3) = @_;
  # Do stuff with $p1, $p1, $p3
}
```

in which case you are working with safe copies of the parameters anyway, and modifying them will have no effect on the actual parameters

Answer (score 8):

`p($x)` and `p($hash->{x})` are fine. You already make a copy of the variable when you do

```
my ($x) = @_;
```

or

```
my $x = shift;
```

No need to create a copy (using `"$x"`) on the caller's side too.

---

If you didn't copy the elements, you could have a problem if you changed a global variable in the sub, and you also pass that global variable as an argument to the sub.

```
$ perl -E'
   my $x;
   sub f { $x = "def"; say $_[0] }
   $x = "abc";
   say $x;
   f($x);
'
abc
def
```

But why would you do that? The plausible instance of this is I can think of is the following:

```
$ perl -E'
   sub f { "def" =~ /(.*)/s; say $_[0] }
   "abc" =~ /(.*)/s;
   say $1;
   f($1);
'
abc
def
```

So maybe `f("$1")` makes sense sometimes, but that's about it.